# Questions related to the Dirichlet series for $\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)^2}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta, dirichlet-series, mellin-transform

This question is related to the following two functions evaluated with the coefficient function $a(n)=\mu(n)\log(n)$.

**(1)** $\quad f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x a(n)$

**(2)** $\quad\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)^2}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a(n)\,n^{-s},\quad\Re(s)>1?$

---

The following plot illustrates $f(x)$ defined in formula (1) above.

---

[image]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of $f(x)$ defined in formula (1)

---

**Question (1)**: Is it true $f(x)$ has an infinite number of zero crossings?

**Question (2)**: What are the limits on $f(x)$ predicted by the Prime Number Theorem and the Riemann Hypothesis?

---

The following figure illustrates the Dirichlet series for $\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)^2}$ defined in (2) above in orange where formula (2) is evaluated over the first $10,000$ terms. The underlying blue reference function is $\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)^2}$.

---

[image: Illustration of formula (2)]

**Figure (2)**: Illustration of formula (2) for $\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)^2}$ (orange curve) and reference function (blue curve)

---

The following four figures illustrate formula (2) for $\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)^2}$ evaluated along the line $\Re(s)=1$ in orange where formula (2) is evaluated over the first $1,000$ terms. The underlying blue reference function is $\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)^2}$. The red discrete portions of the plots illustrate the evaluation of formula (2) for $\frac{\zeta'(1+i\,t)}{\zeta(1+i\,t)^2}$ where $t$ equals the imaginary part of a non-trivial zeta zero.

---

[image: Illustration of absolute part of formula (2) for s=1+it]

**Figure (3)**: Illustration of formula (2) for $\left|\frac{\zeta'(1+i\,t)}{\zeta(1+i\,t)^2}\right|$

---

[image: Illustration of real part of formula (2) for s=1+it]

**Figure (4)**: Illustration of formula (2) for $\Re\left(\frac{\zeta'(1+i\,t)}{\zeta(1+i\,t)^2}\right)$

---

[image: Illustration of imaginary part of formula (2) for s=1+it]

**Figure (5)**: Illustration of formula (2) for $\Im\left(\frac{\zeta'(1+i\,t)}{\zeta(1+i\,t)^2}\right)$

---

[image: Illustration of argument part of formula (2) for s=1+it]

**Figure (6)**: Illustration of formula (2) for $Arg\left(\frac{\zeta'(1+i\,t)}{\zeta(1+i\,t)^2}\right)$

---

**Question (3)**: What is the range of convergence of the Dirichlet series for $\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)^2}$ defined in (2) above? Does it converge only for $\Re(s)>1$, or does it also converge for $\Re(s)=1\land\Im(s)\ne 0$?

---

**Question (4)**: Are there explicit formulas for $f(x)$ and $\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)^2}$ expressed in terms of the non-trivial zeta zeros?

Comment: See those kind of [proof](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~hildebr/ant/main5.pdf) of the PNT. Going from $b(n)=\mu(n)$ to $b(n) \log n$ is one of the main tools of ANT. The PNT and explicit formula for $\sum_{n \le x}\mu(n)$ are not very different to those for $\pi(x), \psi(x)$. You are supposed to understand how the residue theorem applied to the inverse Mellin transform gives a maybe non-convergent explicit formula for $\sum_{n \le x}\mu(n),\sum_{n \le x}\mu(n)\log n$. The convergence is a matter of the density of zeros and Hadamard 3 circles (see Titchmarsh).

Comment: The comment above seems like a good answer to the questions. You would probably get good specific answers if you asked one question at a time...